# Node failed to lookup view "error" in Express/react app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I am working on my app and it worked a few hours ago. But now when I start it, I get the following error.

There is no `/views` directory in `/lib`, but there is in my `src/`. It contains `error.jade.`

I have tried everything. Deleting `/lib`, reinstalling everything...

> Error: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory
>   "/Users/vemundeldegard/all/server/lib/views"
>           at Function.render (/Users/vemundeldegard/all/server/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:580:17)
>           at ServerResponse.render (/Users/vemundeldegard/all/server/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1008:7)
>           at /Users/vemundeldegard/all/server/lib/app.js:47:7
>           at Layer.handle_error (/Users/vemundeldegard/all/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:71:5)
>           at trim_prefix (/Users/vemundeldegard/all/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:315:13)
>           at /Users/vemundeldegard/all/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
>           at Function.process_params (/Users/vemundeldegard/all/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
>           at next (/Users/vemundeldegard/all/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
>           at Layer.handle_error (/Users/vemundeldegard/all/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:67:12)
>           at trim_prefix (/Users/vemundeldegard/all/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:315:13)

App.js

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var { BUILD_DIR, PUBLIC_DIR } = require('./paths');
var reactRenderer = require('./react-renderer');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.get('/', reactRenderer);

app.use(express.static(BUILD_DIR));
app.use(express.static(PUBLIC_DIR));

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Paths.js:

```
"use strict";

var path = require('path');

var BUILD_DIR = path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'client', 'build');
var PUBLIC_DIR = path.join(__dirname, '..', '..', 'public');
module.exports = {
  BUILD_DIR: BUILD_DIR,
  PUBLIC_DIR: PUBLIC_DIR
};
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

(I'd comment, but I don't have enough rep)

The usage of `__dirname` caught my eye -- is it possible you're inadvertently running your app from an incorrect directory (in this case `lib`)?